# Custom Header for SP10

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I'm trying to create a custom header without using SharePoint designer. I am trying to use CSS currently but I when use this code the picture repeats more than once and the header is too narrow.

```
.ms-cui-topBar2{
    background-image: url(/sites/Ga/SiteCollectionImages/ga_header.jpg) !important;
}
```

What else do I need to add to make the picture only repeat once, the header bigger, and place it on a solid color background?

Thanks! I got it to appear correctly now. One more question.

```
    .ms-cui-topBar2{
  background:#4e7cd1 !important;
  background-image:url(/sites/Ga/SiteCollectionImages/ga_header.jpg) !important;
  background-repeat:no-repeat!important;
  background-!important;
  min-height:65px !important;
 }
```

Is it possible to make the header clickable? I want to link it back to another site, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop your image to be repeated in background you will `background-repeat: no-repeat;` attribute of css.

In order to make the header image through only css you can use `background-size: 80px 60px;`, **But then you must ensure that your target browsers support `html5` and `css3`**. Otherwise you have only option to resize the image.

```
.ms-cui-topBar2{
    background-image: url(/sites/Ga/SiteCollectionImages/ga_header.jpg) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80px 60px;
}
```